# Evaluating $\int_0^1\int_0^x\sqrt{4x^2+5}\ dy\ dx$ in calculation for Surface Area

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Find the surface area of the surface $z=x^2+2y$ that lies above the triangular region in the $xy$-plane with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1)$.

My work so far:

If I call this triangular region $R$, then $R=\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq 1,0\leq y\leq x\}$.

Then using the formula for surface area, $$\int_0^1\int_0^x\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)+\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)+1} \ dy \ dx$$

I get $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^x\sqrt{4x^2+5}\ dy\ dx$.

I am encountering some difficulty integrating this. (I've done integration before, but it's been a while.) If I remember how to do this correctly, I will need to use $u-$substitution.

Let $u=4x^2+5$, and so $du=8x\ dx$. So, $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{1}{8x}\left(\sqrt{u}\right)\ du$. I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Also, I'd also just like to make sure that my steps up to this point are correct in calculating surface area for the question posed above. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Note that your first integral is over the $y$ variable. Integrate it out first, and then integrate over $x$. Your substitution will then work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^x\sqrt{4x^2+5}\ dy\ dx=\int_0^1x\sqrt{4x^2+5}\ dx$. This is because I am integrating with respect to $y$, and so by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, it'd just be the integrand  multiplied by $(x-0)=x$.

Then $\int_0^1 \sqrt{4x^2+5}$ can be solved with $u$-substitution.

Let $u=4x^2+5$ and $du=8x \ dx$. So it becomes $\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\sqrt{u}\ du=\frac{1}{8} \dfrac{2u^{3/2}}{3}.$

Reverting back to $x$ and applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus gets us:

$\frac{1}{8}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot(4x^2+5)^{3/2}|^{x=1}_{x=0}=\frac{1}{12}\cdot(9^{3/2}-5^{3/2})$